# when users fill signup form store their info in cookies but not in db

Tags: php

I work on project in which requirement when users sign up into website its information not save in db until admin approved in my idea is we save it in cookies but problem is how we save more than one user info in cookies please guide with most suitable answer

```
setcookie('name','',time()-10,'/','',0);
```

Comment: The admin can't access the cookies.

Comment: What a strange requirement. As Cid stated, how is admin going to access the cookies which are stored client side? Why not store it in DB with a flag that users aren't active yet?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add in the table that stores the logins a boolean row such as `active`

When a user register, his informations are saved to the DB, but `active` is set by default at 0.

If active is 0, a user can't log in.

Only an admin can set active to 1 for the users.

This answer is a bit broad, but unfortunately, your question is a bit broad too

Comment: i discuss your solution to our project manager he said it is possible we need this solution only